# Magnetic fields effect

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

The mass of a Lithium $\rm ^6_3Li$ nucleus is $9.998×10^{−27}\ \rm kg$. It consists of $3$ neutrons and $3$ protons. The Lithium nucleus is traveling in the north direction at speed of $3.67\ \rm km/s$.

If the nucleus suddenly enters a $2.0\ \rm T$ magnetic field directed from east to west, in what direction will the Lithium nucleus be accelerating at the instant it enters the magnetic field.

I want to know the name of the used rule and if anyone can suggest a site or video to learn more about this concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [force on a moving charge in magnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106521/)

Answer (score 0):

The Lorenz force tells you
$\vec{F} = q \vec{v} \times \vec{B},$ in your case $q=+3e$.

The magnitude of $\vec{F}$ is $F=qvbsin(\theta)$;
For the direction, this is ortoghonal to both $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{B}$  . For the verse, there are a lot of way to determine it... I use te following method:

Suppose you have to screw a screw with a screwdriver. Take the first of the two vectors before the operator $\times$, in your case $\vec{v}$. Imagine you rotate this vector over the second one $\vec{B}$ in the way you sweep the smallest corner. Now if in this way you are screwing, follow the motion of your imaging screw and that is the verse of your vector; otherwise, if you are unscrewing, the screw goes in the opposite verse and that's all.
If the charge was negative the verse would be reversed.

In your case take the arrow of the speed and rotate it anti-clockwise (so that the angle is shorter) over the magnetic field's arrow. You are unscrewing so the forces points towars your front (if you're looking it from above). So the acceleration is in the same direction of the force and it follows a circumference where the centripetal force is the Lorenz force.

Look at the following example 
[image: Here it is an example]

See also 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule

Comment: Thanks I understood, but why is q +ve ? Why didn't I consider the q -ve because of electrons

Comment: The $nucleus$ of Li has just 3 protons and 3 neutrons, so the charge is +3e